# How to call a non-exist class in root namespace in php?

Tags: php

That is I want to check is there exist a magic function like __callStatic, when i call a non-exist class's static function, the magic function will be called.

code like that :

```
<?php

function __callStaitc($className, $methodName)
{
     if ($className == 'A') {
           $a = new A();
           return $a->methodName();
     }
}

\A::name();
```

/ Edit1:

for example, I want to implete the code like :

```
<?php

class ADao {

    public function CallA()
    {
        echo "callA" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function CallB()
    {
        echo "callB" . PHP_EOL;
    }

}


function __autoload($classname)
{
    if ($classname == 'A') {
        return new ADao();
    }
}

A::CallB();
```

That is when I call A, it indeed call ADao

Comment: So you basically want to check if a class exists?

Comment: I want to make a auto alias, for example, in namespace A, when i call AClass::function(), if  A does not have class AClass, it will find this Class in B namespace

Comment: it is very likely that you should not do this at all, so please explain why you want to do this, and we will probably be able to show you a better way.

Comment: In laravel route, it has define like that : Route::get('/test/index', 'TestController@index');  but Route does not define in any file. I want to implement the similar

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can define [__autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) function and it will be called every time you're trying to access a non-defined class and the name of the class will be passed as a parameter.

for example:

```
function __autoload( $class_name ) {
    include 'path/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
new NonYetDefinedClass();
```

when the `NonYetDefinedClass` is not yet defined the code above will call the `__autoload` function at it will attempt to include `path/NotYetDefinedClass.php`